# How to compare two partial dates(i.e. todays date with past date) in python?

Tags: python, django

I am newbie in the programming and stackoverflow as well. I know this point might be discussed earlier but i personally couldn't find the one that can help me out.

I am currently working on one of the django projects which has payment interface containing credit card details like credit card number, expiry date, cvv etc.As per client request i have used partial date using django's PartialDateField(Example: February 2025) in expiry date field.

What i supposed to do is if any user enter the past date (lets say March 2019 which is not valid for expiry) then i wanted to set javascript alert from django views.py using comparison logic.

something like this(just a short demo):

Views.py:

```
class billing(View):
      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          pass
      def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
          if entered_date>current_date:        
             javascript alert or something like-> messages.success(request, "Message for alert" )
          submit the form successfully.
```

As a beginner i have no idea how to compare two partial dates so that no one can enter past dates,Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: in which format you are taking entered_date?

Comment: as i wrote in question February 2025...so it would be in month-yyyy format.

Comment: if both of your date are of same format than > will work for you

Comment: i have put > just for demo...all i want is no one can enter the past date and ofcourse present date as well for expiry date...also i have edited my question which might be helpful to give the answer..what to write after if(?) thats the question

Answer (score 0):

So Finally i succeed to achieve what i want.

first of all I converted the partial date(string format) into yyyy-mm-dd like this and it worked:

```
class billing(View):
      def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          pass
      def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
          if **((parse(obj.cc_expiry)).date()) < (datetime.date.today())**:
                messages.success(request, "Expiry Date is not valid.")
                form = PaymentForm()
                return render(request,"html/billing.html",{'form':form,})
          else:
                submit the form
```